# Select all text in input cell to comment out

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, comment

I am wondering if there is any shortcut to select all text in the input cell to comment out. 
Normally to comment a line, I type all the line then use mouse to select all text and then press `Alt + /`. However, I am curious if there is any way to select all text for commenting out or if you know other ways to comment without having to use the mouse in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could press `Ctrl+.` a few times until the whole expression is selected. Or you could press `Up` until you get to the line between your cell and the cell above in, then press `Shift+Down` to select your cell.